# Reading details of application hosted on IIS 5.0 and 5.1 using C#

Tags: c#, iis-5

I am currently working for a client that wants to upgrade their application to the latest version. For this we need to extract details about the application. 
Client's current machine has IIS 5.1 installed, we want to query the IIS and extract all the details about all the applications present on IIS and other details about the application.

My question is how can we do this using C# code.

I have some idea that we need to read the metabase.bin file, but no idea how to proceed on this.

Comment: It is likely that at least some of the files on the IIS web server are compiled, and therefore not easily readable. You need to locate the uncompiled source code, which is probably an ASP.Net application.

Comment: I am more interested in details like application name, its virtual directory, current state of hosted application (running or stopped)... also we don't have access to source code.

Comment: You do not have access to the server itself so that you can use the IIS manager tool? On a Windows machine, that can be accessed in Admin Tools.

Comment: Sigh. You might be able to get some advice at [this other site](http://serverfault.com/) which focuses more on servers.